# Submit form and write to file more than one form field

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I have a code of a form that writes the "email" of user into a `.txt` file in my server.

Here are some things I want to do: Make the form have more than one variable (Like, one line to "name" and another one to "email"), put the form writing in `.txt` prefixes before the "input" texts, and make the output `.txt` file have line breaks between the contents of each variable.

Here is my code currently

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $file = fopen("emaillist.txt","a+");
   fwrite($file,$email);
   fclose($file); 
   print_r(error_get_last());
}
?>
<form action= "" method="post" name="form">
   Email:
   <input type="email" name="email">
   <br>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
   <br>
</form>
```

Can you help me? Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another input to your form. In your code, you have `<input type="email" name="email">` for the email address. Just add a `<input type="text" name="name">` for the name. The field's name (`name="xxx"`) is the key that you can use in PHP in `$_POST['xxx']` to get the information for another line.

Did I understand your question "How can I put the form writting in .txt prefixes before the "input" texts?" correct that you want to have an output in your file like "Email: x@x.x"?

To add a line break, you can write "\n" (if you use a Windows System, use "\r\n") in your strings.

Instead of fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() you can use file_put_contents() which makes your code a bit easier to read.

You can try this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $new_content = "\r\nName: " . $name;
  $new_content .= "\r\nEmail: " . $email;
  file_put_contents('emaillist.txt', $new_content, FILE_APPEND);
  print_r(error_get_last());
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" name="form">
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  Email:
  <input type="email" name="email">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: good answer, but I would recommend using `PHP_EOL` instead of `\r\n` or `\n` (it's better practice, is cross platform, and, in my opinion, easier to read and understand)

Comment: Additionally, there's nothing wrong with `fopen`, `fwrite`, and `fclose`. In fact, since this situation could benefit from using a stream-like system (as it processes one field at a time), that might be cleaner

Comment: @Markasoftware Good point, the only problem is that PHP_EOL will use the *server's* default line endings. So there will be a problem if he uses a Linux server but opens his .txt file on a Windows machine. That's why I would prefer the \r\n way in this case. You are right with the second point - it is not wrong, I just think that a single function call might be easier to understand for a PHP beginner. But that seems to be a matter of taste ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please try with following code .

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $variable = $name ." ". $email.  PHP_EOL;
    $file = fopen("emaillist.txt","a+");
    fwrite($file,$variable);
    fclose($file); 
    print_r(error_get_last());
    }
    ?>
    <form action= "" method="post" name="form">
    Email:
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <br>
    Name:
    <input type="name" name="name">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br>
    </form>
```